# Instance-Specific EventHandler to provide data visibility beyond the Class-Level

Tags: event-handling

May I ask for help with the following?

I am attempting to connect and control three pieces of household electronic equipment by computer through a GlobalCache GC-100 and iTach.  As you will see in the following code, I created a class ("GlobalCacheAdapter") that can communicate and control the equipment, and created an instance of the class for each piece of equipment.  Although each instance seems to work well with communicating and in controlling each piece of equipment, the ****feedback* returned from the equipment*** seems only to be visible at the defining class level's - "ReaderThreadProc" procedure.  Further processing of the feedback is required for each piece of equipment and I am uncertain as to how to **forward this feedback at the equipment specific instance-level**.  I suspect that an instance-specific EventHandler will need to be implemented; however I am not aware as to how to implement this type of instance-specific EventHandler in order to complete processing and update the appropriate controls.

Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

```
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {

             // Create three new instances of GlobalCacheAdaptor and connect.
             // GC-100 (Elan) 192.168.1.70 4998  
             // GC-100 (TuneSuite) 192.168.1.70 5000  
             // GC iTach (Lighting) 192.168.1.71 4999

             private GlobalCacheAdaptor elanGlobalCacheAdaptor;
             private GlobalCacheAdaptor tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor;
             private GlobalCacheAdaptor lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor;

             public Form1()
             {
                  InitializeComponent();

                  elanGlobalCacheAdaptor = new GlobalCacheAdaptor();
                  elanGlobalCacheAdaptor.ConnectToDevice(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.70"), 4998);
                  tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor = new GlobalCacheAdaptor();
                  tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor.ConnectToDevice(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.70"), 5000);
                  lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor = new GlobalCacheAdaptor();
                  lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor.ConnectToDevice(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.71"), 4999);

                  elanTextBox.Text = elanGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
                  tuneSuiteTextBox.Text = tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
                  lutronTextBox.Text = lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
           }

           private void btnZoneOnOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {    elanGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("sendir,4:3,1,40000,4,1,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,800" + Environment.NewLine); }
           private void btnSourceInput1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    elanGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("sendir,4:3,1,40000,1,1,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,278,20,179,20,179,20,179,20,780" + Environment.NewLine); }        
           private void btnSystemOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {    elanGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("sendir,4:3,1,40000,1,1,20,184,20,184,20,184,20,184,20,184,20,286,20,286,20,286,20,184,20,184,20,184,20,820" + Environment.NewLine); }

           private void btnLightOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     {    lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("sdl,14,0,0,S2\x0d"); }
           private void btnLightOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      {    lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("sdl,14,100,0,S2\x0d"); }

           private void btnChannel31_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {    tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("\xB8\x4D\xB5\x33\x31\x00\x30\x21\xB8\x0D"); }
           private void btnChannel30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {    tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor.SendMessage("\xB8\x4D\xB5\x33\x30\x00\x30\x21\xB8\x0D"); }
      }
}

public class GlobalCacheAdaptor
{
      public Socket _multicastListener;
      public string _preferredDeviceID;
      public IPAddress _deviceAddress;
      public Socket _deviceSocket;
      public StreamWriter _deviceWriter;
      public bool _isConnected;
      public int _port;
      public IPAddress _address;
      public string _line;

      public GlobalCacheAdaptor() { }
      public static readonly GlobalCacheAdaptor Instance = new GlobalCacheAdaptor();

      public bool IsListening { get { return _multicastListener != null; } }

      public GlobalCacheAdaptor ConnectToDevice(IPAddress address, int port)
      {
            if (_deviceSocket != null) _deviceSocket.Close();
            try
            {
                  _port = port;
                  _address = address;
                  _deviceSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                  _deviceSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(address, port)); ;
                  _deviceAddress = address;
                  var stream = new NetworkStream(_deviceSocket);
                  var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                  var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { NewLine = "\r", AutoFlush = true };
                  _deviceWriter = writer;
                  writer.WriteLine("getdevices");
                  var readerThread = new Thread(ReaderThreadProc) { IsBackground = true };
                  readerThread.Start(reader);
                  _isConnected = true;
                  return Instance;
           }
           catch { DisconnectFromDevice(); MessageBox.Show("ConnectToDevice Error."); throw; }
}
     public void SendMessage(string message)
     {
           try
           {
                 var stream = new NetworkStream(_deviceSocket);
                 var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                 var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { NewLine = "\r", AutoFlush = true };
                 _deviceWriter = writer;
                 writer.WriteLine(message);
                 var readerThread = new Thread(ReaderThreadProc) { IsBackground = true };
                 readerThread.Start(reader);
           }
           catch { MessageBox.Show("SendMessage() Error."); }
    }

    public void DisconnectFromDevice()
    {
         if (_deviceSocket != null)
         {
               try { _deviceSocket.Close(); _isConnected = false; }
               catch { MessageBox.Show("DisconnectFromDevice Error."); }
               _deviceSocket = null;
         }
        _deviceWriter = null;
        _deviceAddress = null;
    }

    **private void ReaderThreadProc(object state)**
    {
          var reader = (StreamReader)state;
          try
          {
              while (true)
              {
                 var line = reader.ReadLine();
                 if (line == null) break;
                 _line = _line + line + Environment.NewLine;
              }
             **// Feedback from each piece of equipment is visible here.
               // Need to create EventHandler to notify the TextBoxes to update with _line**
           }
           catch { MessageBox.Show("ReaderThreadProc Error."); }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, you want to do something like this?

[image]

You need to know when a GlobalCacheAdapter updates and which one updated in order to update textboxes on a form. My question to you is this - do you actually need to know which updated?

If you declare in your class an event handler like this:

```
public class GlobalCacheAdaptor
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Updated;

    protected virtual void OnUpdated()
    {
        var handler = Updated;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        // When an update is received, raise Updated event
        OnUpdated();
    }
}
```

Then in your form subscribe to Updated for all three GlobalCacheHandler instances

```
public Form1()
{
    elanGlobalCacheAdaptor.Updated += (s,e) => 
    {
        elanTextBox.Text = elanGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
    }

    tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor.Updated += (s,e) => 
    {
        tuneSuiteTextBox.Text = tuneSuiteGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
    }

    lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor.Updated += (s,e) => 
    {
        lutronTextBox.Text = lutronGlobalCacheAdaptor._line;
    }
}
```

You should be able to update the correct text box when the appropriate cache handler raises the Updated event.

Finally you may need to handle cross-thread interactions. if so, [see this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), particularly the part "Thread-Safe Calls to a Windows Forms Control"

Comment: Thank you Dr. ABT. Excellent and elegant advice!  Now that I've got the 'feedback' visible, I find that the 'ReaderThreadProc' does not dependably return all of the data coming from the port. Unfortunately, this was not something I could test until I gained visibility.  Any advise?  How I wish you worked at the next desk over from mine!  Thank you again Dr.

Comment: No idea, sorry :) I suggest you use Debug.WriteLine logging throughout your app to try to trace what's going on where. If you're still stuck post another question but hardware related issues could be anything!